# Guarding against HTML IDs in the JS global namespace

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am using Require.js in a project. If you’re defining a module, the variable `define` is added to the global namespace.

Recently I had a variable name conflict [but curiously, only in Safari] because there was a HTML tag with an ID of `define`, and according to the [HTML5 specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#named-access-on-the-window-object):

> The Window interface supports named properties. The supported property names at any moment consist of the following:
>
> - …
> - …
> - **the value of the id content attribute of any HTML element in the active document with a non-empty id content attribute.**

I think it’s a terrible idea to pollute the JS global namespace with every HTML element that has an ID, but my opinion alone is not enough to change the way a browser behaves.

In my particular instance, I’ve found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600813/how-can-requirejs-functions-be-kept-out-of-the-global-namespace) that will wrap Require.js; but in a more general sense: is there a way to guard against this detail in the specification? Is there a technique for preventing this GNS pollution (without the obvious answer: “Don’t use IDs”)? Could the conflict at least be made obvious to the developer (which might not be me), through the JS console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior of HTML5 has no effect on RequireJS itself. I've run the following in Firefox and Chrome. As expected, the `define` symbol in the global space was RequireJS's define function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml; charset=utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="define">Paragraph.</p>
    <button id="redefine">Redefine</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      console.log("before requirejs:", typeof window.define);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/require.js"></script>
    <script>
      require.config({
          baseUrl: "./js",
          paths: {
              jquery: 'jquery-1.10.2'
          },
      });
      console.log("requirejs loaded:", typeof window.define);
      require(["jquery"], function ($) {
          $("#redefine").click(function () {
              $("#define").replaceWith("<p id='define'>New paragraph.</p>");
              console.log("redefined:", typeof window.define);
              require(["foo"], function (foo) {
                  console.log(foo);
              });
          });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I use `typeof` to avoid getting a dump of the entire source of the function. It is enough for our purposes. The "Redefine" button is to simulate a change to the DOM tree which one might think would overwrite the value of `window.define`. (The module `foo` is a trival module that only returns the value `"foo"`.) The `require` inside the click handler shows that RequireJS is still functional. Using the code above, the output to the console shows that:

1. Even if originally `window.define` was the DOM element, RequireJS will redefine `define` to its own value.
2. Once RequireJS has defined `define`, changes to the DOM tree do not change it.

So RequireJS does not need to be protected from it.

But what about code that insists on using `window.define` to access an element with an id of "define"? Such code is defective and should be fixed. This SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here) covers the issue very well. Even if RequireJS were made to avoid touching the global `define`, the code which relies on `window.define` being a DOM element would still be brittle.

> Is there a technique for preventing this GNS pollution (without the obvious answer: “Don’t use IDs”)?

Other than the obvious answer, no. (I take "use something else than IDs" to be equivalent to "don't use IDs".)

> Could the conflict at least be made obvious to the developer (which might not be me), through the JS console?

A JS virtual machine could probably detect the conflict but I don't know of any that does this.

#### But What About Safari?

It's a bug in how Safari handles global variables in JavaScript. No other browser behaves the say Safari does.

[This repository](https://github.com/lddubeau/define-conflict) contains a set of files illustrating the problem. The `index.html` file will show a failure on the console if loaded in Safari. It loads fine in Firefox, Chrome, IE and Opera. The `test.html` file pinpoints the issue. All browsers except Safari treat a variable declaration in JavaScript like `var foo` at the top level scope as shadowing any variable of the same name that was created due to an element having an `id` attribute set. Loaded in any browser except Safari, the `console.log` that outputs `start of redefine:` will show `undefined undefined` for the values of the variables. In Safari, it shows `p#define p#define`.

An issue [has been filed](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/1005) with RequireJS to suggest a change that would take care of this case.

If the suggested change does not go through, then the workaround is to execute `define = undefined` before loading RequireJS. There is no need to do anything more.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I could only observe this behaviour in Safari. Chrome and Firefox seemed to ignore this detail in the spec, or perhaps guard against conflicts in some way.

Comment: That suggests a bug in Safari.

Comment: If it’s written in the specification, then it isn’t really classed as a bug.